# PHP Combine Single Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure how to exactly explain what I am trying to do but I try to explain using an example.

```
$products = array("35","37","43");
```

Say if I have above array how can I create a result array that will look like this.

```
$related_products = array (

array (35,37),

array (35,43),

array (37,35),

array (37.43),

array (43,35),

array (43, 37) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two loops to catch all combinations:

```
$products = array("35","37","43");
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($products); $j++) {
        if($i !== $j) {
            $result[] = array(
                $products[$i],
                $products[$j]
            );
        }   
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 37
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37
            [1] => 35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37
            [1] => 43
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
            [1] => 35
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
            [1] => 37
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add one item to main array using array_push method like this,

```
$products = array("35","37","43");
$data = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($products); $j++) {
        if($i !== $j) {
              array_push($data,array($products[$i],$products[$j]));
            );
        }   
    }
}

print_r($data);
```